# Cursing in G-d’s name

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, beit-din-court, curse, bava-kamma

The Gemara (Bava Kamma 93a) says that the reason why Sarah passed away before Avraham was because she told him: “may G-d judge between us”.

The Gemara learns from there that it is forbidden to call upon Devine judgement, unless there is no judge down here on earth who can take care of the matter.

The question is: in a case when there is no judge available down here, would one be allowed to use Hashem’s name when calling upon Devine judgment, or would that still fall under the prohibition of cursing a fellow man in G-d’s name?

Comment: Are you assuming cursing is the same as invoking judgement? Or is that your question?

Comment: @shmosel, yes, it’s part of the question